# Reading Data From a Server into WebWorks

Tags: sql, json, html, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I am designing an app with the Blackberry WebWorks SDK (HTML5) which needs to obtain data from an SQL server and display it on the app in a simple list. What is the best way to approach the transfer of data in this case? I have been researching and have come across JSON; would I have to use something like that to do the parsing between the server? I have never dealt with server sided languages so the details of how I would accomplish this are a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use JSON to transfer data between your server & BB device. Since JSON has small memory & bandwidth footprint. If you are planning to save data in local storage use HTML5 sql database. Local storage is not supported in BB smart phones.

JSON parser [if you are not using jQuery] - json2.js

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Comment: Since I'm assuming the javascript file stays on the blackberry device, how does it communicate between the server? I would assume there needs to be some php script connecting mysql to obtain the data. I'm a bit confused on this setup, since I'm seperating a javascript file and a php file that I would normally have together on the server.

Comment: Okay - All your javascript files, html files, css and images (icons & other offline files) should be served locally (from device itself). Only fetch data from server using AJAX in the form of JSON.